# How can I not use a scope if an attribute is null

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, dry

I have the following in my controller:

```
  @filt= params[:filter] || 'no_filter'
if params[:subcategory].nil? || params[:subcategory] == "null"
  @resources = Resource.find_by_category(params[:category]).approved.send(@filt).page(params[:page]).per(30)
else
  @resources = Resource.find_by_category(params[:category]).find_by_subcategory(params[:subcategory]).approved.send(@filt).page(params[:page]).per(30)
end
```

I want to reduce this code down so that I don't duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

```
@filt= params[:filter] || 'no_filter'
r = Resource.find_by_category(params[:category])
r = r.find_by_subcategory(params[:subcategory]) unless [nil, 'null'].include? params[:subcategory] 
@resources = r.approved.send(@filt).page(params[:page]).per(30)
```

You don't have to put it all in one line to chain scopes, like `Model.scope1.scope2` etc.. You can do it by `s = Model.scope1; s = s.scope2`, as in the code sample above.